# How to grant full disk access to a user without GUI on macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, shell, authorization

I need to launch shell scripts from a process that uses a kind of user that has no gui, but those scripts need full disk access, but since that user has no login screen I can't use the system preferences to grant  that access.

For the records that's for Filemaker Server. Filemaker server creates a fmserver user account, and uses this to perform server side scripts. Therefore the shell script it runs are ran as fmserver user. But of course fmserver user has no gui, so can set it.

So how do I grant full disk access to application (terminal and shell commands like smb) to that fmserver user ?

Or is there a way to remove all that disk access authorizations completely on the whole computer ?